# Using Varnish as a reverse proxy with mutiple vhosts

Tags: varnish

I have only one public ip address so use Varnish as a reverse proxy for multiple servers. Here is the configuration.

1st physical server Varnish/Apache - port 80, port 8080, ip address 10.0.0.40

2nd physical server 3 Drupal Vhosts - port 80, ip address 10.0.0.30

3rd physical server 2 Non Drupal Vhosts - port 80, ip address 10.0.0.31

In /etc/sysconfig/varnish,

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \ -T localhost:6082 \ -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \ -u varnish -g varnish \ -S /etc/varnish/secret \ -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"

In default vcl,

backend default { .host = "127.0.0.1"; .port = "8080"; }

Reverse proxy is working ok and I can see Varnish cache working by checking http header. However I am not sure above configuration is correct or optimal, especially only one backend definition on default vcl file. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach:

*NGINX* > *VARNISH* > *APACHE*

- **Nginx**: to handle SSL termination easily and also you can use it to cache the static content. As far as I know that *Nginx* is better than *Varnish* in caching the static content also *Varnish* is not supposed to cache the static content.
- **Varnish**: will receive requests from *Nginx* and pass it to *Apache*.
- **Apache**: will act as a load balancer which will send the requests to the backend servers (Drupal/Non-drupal)

Check the following resources:

1- [HTTPS Everywhere With Nginx, Varnish And Apache](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/09/https-everywhere-with-nginx-varnish-apache/)

2- [Simple load balancing with Apache](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/simple-load-balancing-with-apache/)

If my answer is not clear enough let me know.

Comment: Okay. At this point I don't plan to use HTTPS so I am not sure what is a good point to use another layer which is Nginx cause post you have mentioned talks about Varnish as a cache as well.

Comment: Using Nginx makes it easier to manage SSL, also its better to cache the static content using NGINX

Comment: Ok. So Nginx will be act as a cache and Varnish as a reverse proxy then? If so, Nginx will run port 80 for http(no ssl), Varnish port 80 for Nginx and 8080 for Apache, and Apache port 8080 for Varnish and 80 for back end servers?

Comment: Nginx will be on PUBLIC_IP:80 (Works as a cache for static content and to manage SSL if exist), Varnish will be on LOCALHOST:80 (Receiving from NGINX and sending to Apache and Caching the dynamic content [PHP requests for exmple] ), Apache will be on LOCALHOST:8080 or 82 (Which receives from Varnish and sending to the backend servers)

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand it. After verifiying Nginx was working, Varnish was enabled. It look like everything is cache so age count is not increasing.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 18:53:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 01:39:44 GMT
ETag: "143853-1-51f6eca45f800"
Content-Length: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 03:53:14 GMT
X-Varnish: 2
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Powered-By: 10.0.0.45
X-Proxy-Cache-NGINX: HIT
X-Real-IP: 175.126.37.104
Accept-Ranges: bytes

Comment: Expire settings for static contents are in backend servers (httpd.conf). Two questions. 1. How can I make Varnish only cache dynamic contents (nothing is declared on default.vcl)? 2. How can I make Nginx to show age count is increased or cache only static contents? Here is the definition of default.conf from Nginx.   proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";    location / {

proxy_cache my_zone;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache-NGINX $upstream_cache_status;